# How to use VIM's toupper within a replacement string?

Tags: vi

Is it possible to use toupper in replacement string?
Suppose, there are member Declarations like this:

```
int myVar;
```

I want to make the first letter of variable name to a capital-letter:

```
int MyVar;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
:1,$s/\(\w\+\)\s\+\(\w\)\(\w*\)\s*;/\1 \=toupper(submatch(\2))\3;/
```

Finally, I could use \u for doing this:

```
:1,$s/\(\w\+\)\s\+\(\w\)\(\w*\)\s*;/\1 \u\2\3;/
```

But I am still curious if using functions like toupper within the replacement string works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
:1,$s/\(\w\+\)\s\+\(\w\)\(\w*\)\s*;/\=submatch(1)." ".toupper(submatch(2)).submatch(3).";"/
```

Comment: Great, it works! Thank you very much! I see, the strings should be enclosed in "" and concatenated with other strings or function results using dot. Thank you very much!